# Store real line break in db

Tags: php, mysql, line-breaks

I have a field called eol (type: varchar) in my mysql database.

I set it to default \r\n in PHPMyAdmin.

if i doing a `SELECT` using PDO i do not recieve a real line break.

If I var_dump my result like this:

```
var_dump(unpack('C*',$eol));
```

The result is:

```
array(4) { 
[1]=> int(92) 
[2]=> int(114) 
[3]=> int(92) 
[4]=> int(110) 
}
```

which is in fact:

- [backslash]
- r
- [backslash]
- n

If I var_dump a real line break

```
var_dump(unpack('C*',"\r\n"));
```

The result is:

```
array(2) { 
[1]=> int(13) 
[2]=> int(10) 
}
```

How do I store a real line break properly in mysql?

**EDIT:**

@all if i doing simple

var_dump("\r\n");

it will be shown like this:

```
string(2) "
"
```

which is nice but I cannot see the real chars!

Comment: I never had your problems. Let's say you have a textarea and linebreaks. You just save them in database like they are and show them with [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php). That's it.

Comment: @machineaddict it is not for that case. I need to store the line break information in a seperate field to be able to parse CSV Files with different line breaks.

Comment: Could it be that phpmyadmin escaped the value when you entered `\r\n` for the default value?

Comment: Then why do you `unpack` when you saved them as string `\r\n`?

Comment: I am doing the unpack for debugging reasons to be able to see the real chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the way mySQL database stores these values. PHPMyAdmin is just a GUI tool. Hence whatever you enter are considered as individual characters.

A simple example is the ASCII. `0x0A` represents line feed but if you enter that using PHPMyAdmin you will get those characters instead of line feed. This is similar to that. I have stored line feeds into mysql columns using queries without any trouble.

For example -

```
insert into `evaluation_answer_versions` (`evaluation_answers_answer_id`, `question_version_id`, `answer_text`, `score`, `hidden`) values (1, 1, "\r\nabc", 1, 'n');
```

works as expected.

Comment: Yes i recognized that, too. The default value doesn't work. I removed it and inserted the value via query and everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `pack`, special characters do get parsed when using double quotes:

```
var_dump("\r\n"); // 2 bytes CR LF, not 4 byte '\r\n' literal
```

You should maybe use in MySQL a 2 byte binary field instead of varchar.

```
$dbh->query("INSERT INTO x SET eol = '\r\n'");
```

Inserting `\r\n` through phpMyAdmin, it will escape the characters to `\\r\\n`.

Comment: If i use a 2-Byte Binary field PHPMyAdmin displays: invalid default value \r\n for field eol. It handles it as 4 bytes.

Comment: when entering `\r\n` through phpMyAdmin, this is 4 bytes literal because phpMyAdmin escapes the characters. You cannot insert this with phpMyAdmin. It changes `\r\n` to `\\r\\n`. The default value set by phpMyAdmin is also escaped. You need to generate the whole table through a query instead.

Comment: ok you are right. It is a PHPMyAdmin issue. I removed the default value and inserted it with my record (Fieldtype: Varchar). The result is that i recieved a proper line break `array(2) { [1]=> int(13) [2]=> int(10) }` when doing  `var_dump(unpack('C*',$eol));`!.

Comment: Sorry, you helped me but I had to accept @nightgaunt's answer. It pointed directly to the problem. The "you dont't need to unpack" hint and the "2-byte binary" hint did not solve the problem. Inserting via query solved the problem. However thank you very much.

Comment: @steven My last edit, pointing out that phpMyAdmin escapes the new line characters was 32 minutes ago while nightgaunt's answer was 25 minutes ago. I'm fine with your decision anyways, I don't take this personal or too serious to complain :-) Glad your problem got solved!